# How to install and configure Redis server on Amazon Linux 2023 (AL2023)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, fedora, redis, amazon-linux, aws-ec2

Amazon Linux 2023 is loosely based on Fedora 34, 35 and 36 as per aws:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/relationship-to-fedora.html

However `redis` package is not available in AL2023, instead `redis6` is available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages-al2023-20230322.html

I tried installing it using `sudo dnf -y install redis6` and it installed successfully. But I'm not able to find any redis configuration file. A `redis6` folder got created and is accessible using `sudo cd /etc/redis6` however the folder is empty and doesn't have any configuration file. `ls` inside `/etc/redis6` is not returning anything.

What is the right way to install redis server in AL2023?

[UPDATE]
`ls` command didn't return any files inside `/etc/redis6` folder but a configuration file is actually available. Using `sudo nano /etc/redis6/redis6.conf` I was able to update the existing redis config file to use systemd and set a password.

So the redis server is working fine now, just need to use `redis6` instead of `redis` everywhere in AL2023, for ex `redis6-cli`.

Comment: Tested redis server installation using redis6-cli and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo dnf install -y redis6
sudo systemctl start redis6
sudo systemctl enable redis6
sudo systemctl is-enabled redis6
redis6-server --version
redis6-cli ping
```

Comment: any suggestions how to send redis metrics to cloudwatch

Answer (score 3):

You can try building it from source. This way you can get latest version as well. These instruction can be found at:

1. Installation from [source](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/installation/install-redis-from-source/).
2. Additional Steps after [installation](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/#install-redis-more-properly).

Here are the steps for the installation on Amazon Linux 2023.

1. Install the `latest` version of redis from source.

```bash
  sudo yum update
  sudo yum install -y make gcc
  mkdir redis && cd redis && wget https://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz 
  tar -xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz && cd redis-stable/
  make distclean  # for clean build
  make
  sudo make install
```

2. Run server using `redis-server`. At this point redis should be installed on your instance and will only accept connections from same instance. This can be checked by running `redis-cli ping` in a separate terminal.
3. Next step is to enable redis to accept connections from other clients and run after restart. These instructions are referenced from [docs](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/#install-redis-more-properly). Run following to make sure `redis-server` is started after restart.

```bash
  cd ~/redis/redis-stable
  sudo mkdir /etc/redis
  sudo mkdir /var/redis
  sudo cp utils/redis_init_script /etc/init.d/redis_6379
  sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/redis_6379 # Optional
  sudo cp redis.conf /etc/redis/6379.conf
  sudo chkconfig --add redis_6379
  sudo chkconfig redis_6379 on
```

4. Make config changes to accept connection from other instances. NOTE: These config changes will open redis for external connections. Make sure to have proper security config for the instance.
   Open config file:

```bash
  sudo nano /etc/redis/6379.conf
```

```
  Change the following values from default to as indicated
```

```bash
  bind 127.0.0.1 -::1 ->> bind 0.0.0.0 -::1 
  protected-mode yes ->> protected-mode no 
  daemonize no ->> daemonize yes 
  logfile "" ->> logfile "/var/log/redis_6379.log" 
  dir ./ ->> dir /var/redis/6379
```

5. Restart the instance and `redis` should start automatically in daemon mode and accept external connections.

After above steps you will have redis installed with following configuration.

- config file at: `/etc/redis/6379.conf`
- log file at: `/var/log/redis_6379.log`
- auto restart enabled (via runlevels)
- To stop run, `redis-cli shutdown`
- To start server (if #4 skipped), `sudo redis-server /etc/redis/6379.conf --daemonize yes`

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a ton of time. One step is missing => sudo mkdir /var/redis/6379. It can be found in original guide (https://redis.io/docs/install/install-redis/)

Comment: any suggestion on how to send redis metrics to cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
sudo amazon-linux-extras install redis6

sudo systemctl start redis

sudo systemctl enable redis

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the help. But AL2023 doesn't support amazon-linux-extras like Amazon Linux 2.0, so running the above commands is returning the following error:
`sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found`
Only packages that are part of the `amazonlinux` repository can be installed in AL2023

Answer (score 0):

To install Redis 7 on Amazon Linux 2023 with TLS support:

```
sudo yum -y install openssl-devel gcc
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make distclean
make redis-cli BUILD_TLS=yes
sudo install -m 755 src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin/
```